# Memoire sur la courbure des surfaces by Sophie Germain

Tags: reference-request

Does anyone know where to find a pdf version of this article written by Sophie Germain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old issues of Crelle are available online at 
[this site](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/toc/?PPN=PPN243919689).  The paper you want seems to be the first one in [this issue](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN243919689_0007&DMDID=DMDLOG_0003&LOGID=LOG_0003&PHYSID=PHYS_0004)